# Find the number of days in each month between 2 given dates

Tags: tableau-api

My input is :

```
catg_desc   equipment_number            present_date
STANDBY             123                    24-06-2018
OTHERS              123                    21-04-2019
READY               123                    26-04-2019
JOB                 256                    26-04-2019
```

I have solved the scenario in postgresql but is multiplying the number of records. I don't want to increase the number of records in the final table as that can go upto 35,000,000 and difficult to handle in tableau.

using generate_series, we are inserting the data of missing months.

Expected Output:

```
catg_desc   equipment_number    present_date    Mon-yy  no of days  
STANDBY        123                  24-06-2018  Jun-18      7   
STANDBY        124                  24-06-2018  Jul-18      31  
STANDBY        125                  24-06-2018  Aug-18      31  
STANDBY        126                  24-06-2018  Sep-18      30  
STANDBY        127                  24-06-2018  Oct-18      31  
STANDBY        128                  24-06-2018  Nov-18      30  
STANDBY        129                  24-06-2018  Dec-18      31  
STANDBY        130                  24-06-2018  Jan-19      31  
STANDBY        131                  24-06-2018  Feb-19      28  
STANDBY        132                  24-06-2018  Mar-19      31  
STANDBY        133                  24-06-2018  Apr-19      20  
OTHERS         123                  24-06-2018  Apr-19      5   
READY          123                  26-04-2019  Apr-19      30  
READY          124                  26-04-2019  May-19      22  (till current date)
JOB            256                  26-04-2019  Apr-19      5   
JOB            256                  26-04-2019  May-19      22  (till current date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 date fields then use datediff(). create a calculated field as below
DATEDIFF('day',[Startdate],[enddate)

Comment: datediff() simply gives no of days between two dates. But I need to show no of days in each month between 2 dates

Comment: The Tableau technique best suited for this involves a custom table calc. So learn how they work well first on simple cases. Read the help on table calcs and understand how partitioning and addressing work. Test your understanding usin the index(), size(0, first(), last(), lookup() functions along with different partitioning or compute using settings. Then learn about Previous_Value() which is a bit odd but will let you traverse recursively through query results. If you include a Month/Year field in your viz on some shelf, then you combine the features above to solve the problem.